# What is the effect on custom chrome plugin if JS is disabled on browser?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

What is the effect on custom chrome plugin  if JS is disabled on browser?
Which part of the chrome plugin will work and which part will not work?
Will background script  work or will both background and foreground  scripts both will not work?

Comment: The only thing that won't work is the script added by your extension into the web page via a `<script>` element, AFAIK. P.S. it's not a plugin, it's an extension.